# Tomcat port 80 - corrupted websocket messages

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, websocket

I am currently trying to write a small web application that makes use of websockets. The application is doing a broadacast to all connected clients. This works quite well as long as the Tomcat Container is running on a port different from port 80.

For this scenario think of the web application broadcasting messages all the time.

The working behaviour is the following (i.e. running on port different from 80):

1. Client (Browser) connects to the server successfully
2. Client immediately receives messages (i.e. websocket callback function is invoked)

As soon as I configure it to run on port 80 the following behaviour could be observed:

1. Client (Browser) connects to the server successfully
2. From the start no invocation of callback can be observed via console.log(...)
3. After some time the debug output from the onmessage callback is shown all at once having all the same timestamp, though the timespan between 5 broadcasts is definitely more than a second

Console Log:

```
Event data: {"aktuell":50,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":55,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":60,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":65,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":70,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":75,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":80,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":85,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":90,"total":788,"msg":"Indexiere Artikel"} at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
Event data: {"aktuell":95,"total":784{"aktuell":50,"total":788, at Mon Mar 03 2014 14:24:22 GMT+0100
```

This behaviour is shown using Tomcat 7.0.42, 7.0.52 and Tomcat 8.0.3. For the client side IE 10, Firefox 21 and Chrome 33 have been used.

It seems to me that the websockets' content is somehow buffered to a size of about 510 bytes (observed when stripping debug messages down to the message content only). Even if I change the JSON message structure it will be a total of 510 bytes.

**Is there anything that I missed that is different when working with port 80?**

Just as an additional information, on the server side I use

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message)
```

to send the message and on the client side I use

```
ws = new WebSocket(url); // Open connection
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data); // Stripped down version
}
```

to handle any incoming event.

Comment: Where the ports you were using other than 80 below 1024?

Comment: Checked for a firewall, or anti-virus app(s)?  Port 80 is in a list of ports called reserved ports that are treated differently.

Comment: I used port 81 as well as 8080. It worked well for the both of them.

Comment: If you turn off your tomcat instance do you get the same behavior or a server not found error?

Comment: How should that help? I cannot even open the web application (which is hosting the websockets client) if the server is down. And even if I use some sort of generic client or open the page before shutting the server down - the websocket connection cannot be established.